# return all possible combinations of values in columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server

How do I return a list of all combinations of values in 4 columns so that they are new rows in Microsoft SQL Server 2012
e.g.

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
1  a  g  x
2  b  h  y
```

and turn it into

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
1  a  g  x
1  a  g  y
1  a  h  x
1  a  h  y
```

and so on having all (2X2X2X2)=16 rows in 4 columns

Similar solution for 2 columns has been answered on

[Return all possible combinations of values on columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql)

I need the solution for 4 columns

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 5):

With a cross join

```
select 
    t1.c1,
    t2.c2,
    t3.c3,
    t4.c4
from 
    yourtable t1 cross join
    yourtable t2 cross join
    yourtable t3 cross join
    yourtable t4
```

Answer (score 2):

As the link you provided had a good answer, modified below

```
select 
  distinct
  t1.C1,
  t2.C2,
  t3.C3,
  t4.C4
from 
  MyTable t1,
  MyTable t2,
  MyTable t3,
  MyTable t4
```

Comment: I think you want to make this "t3.C3" and "t4.C4". Using explicit cross join would be better for reading, so the point goes to podiluska anyway :-)

Comment: Sorry for the obvious error here... nice catch! :-)

As a comparison to the almost identical solution posted here i will keep the alternative