# Combine Two Disparate Result Sets Into One

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't think of how to phrase it in google, so here I am.

I have a table of users like so:

```
create table MyUser
(
    Id int
)

insert into MyUser(Id)
select 1 union
select 2 union
select 3 union
select 4 union
select 5
```

And a table of objects like so:

```
create table Object
(
    Id int
)

insert into Object(Id)
select 1 union
select 2 union
select 3
```

What I want as a result set is this (first column is MyUser.Id, second is Object.Id):

```
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 1
...
```

Basically, I want a row for every combination of these two tables. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql) is similar, but I can't rely on values in one table being less than or greater than the values. So, basically, I believe what I want can be described as the cartesian product between two tables with no relationship.

How would I do that? I've been playing around with CTE's/subqueries and UNIONs, but I can't figure out how to filter out the dummy values for the UNION statements that represent the column not being selected in that part of the UNION and the CTE/subqueries may not be able to do what I'm wanting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cross join

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyUser 
CROSS JOIN Object
```

or using old style joins (which I don't recommend)

```
SELECT *
FROM MyUser, Object
```

Comment: Perfect! I had `CROSS APPLY` stuck in my head, which obviously isn't right. I've never been in this situation before so I couldn't think of the right syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyUser, Object
```