# lookup function join based on multiple fields

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, lookup

[image]

Above picture is the way I want my report to look. #expiry and expiry are dataset1 and #delete and delete are from dataset2. I am using matrix to create this report. The data for expiry looks good but when I try to use the dataset2 for delete rows (using lookup function)  the data is wrong for delete part. Is there any way that i can use dataset2 for my report or use lookup function join based on organization and date field.
SSRS 2008 r2
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can combine two text fields together with **&** to make a unique identifier to use in a **LOOKUP**.

```
=LOOKUP(Fields!ORGANIZATION.Value & "|" & CSTR(Fields!DATE.Value), Fields!ORGANIZATION.Value & "|" & CSTR(Fields!DATE.Value),  Fields!DELETE.Value, "DataSet2")
```

**Update:** 
If you can't JOIN your datasets beforehand and your organization and dates may not appear in both, you'll need add all the possibilities. There are two ways to do this.

You can RIGHT JOIN your current **dataset1** query to a query that has all of your possible ORG/Date combinations.

OR

You can create a separate dataset with just the dates and organizations and base the table on it. Then you'd need to get both **EXPIRY** and **DELETE** using **LOOKUP**.

For either method, you'd need a query like this to get all the combinations:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2015-11-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2015-11-30';

;WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS myDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(D ,1 ,myDate) as myDate
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(D, 1, myDate) <=  @EndDate
)

SELECT myDate, ORGANIZATION 
INTO #TEMP_ORG_DATES 
FROM Dates 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ORGANIZATION FROM YourTable)
```

You can use this TEMP table as the table base or RIGHT JOIN this to your current EXPIRY query on date and ORG.

[Return all possible combinations of values on columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql)

Comment: Thanks. i got most of records and all are correct except there are few of them missing for delete part.. what can be the reason. lets say for organization B it missed for few dates.

Comment: Are your date fields formatted the same in both datasets? One might give **m/d/yyyy** while the other is **mm/dd/yyyy**. The dates look funky for the ones that should be the 4th and 5th. You can try using FORMAT instead of CSTR for the date fields - `FORMAT(Fields!DATE.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")`.

Comment: i think the issue is due to for organization part. it is taking the values from first part only not from other. how can i use the third dataset or using same dataset so that the organization show union all for all organization names. Dataset 1= A,B,C,D Dataset2= A,B,C,E,F .then organization should ave A,B,C,D,E,F

Comment: the dates was just a typo. I checked it they are ok.

Comment: @user3438498 - If you can't JOIN them in a single query before hand you won't be able to here. I updated my answer with info on what you could do.