# SQL - Return All Possible Combinations of Values in a Column by Means of Two New Columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, combinations

I want to return all possible combinations of values in a column by means of two new columns. E.g. my column consists out of the values (A,B,C,D). The possible combinations of those values are (A,B), (A,C), (A,D), (B,C), (B,D), (C,D), (A,B,C), (B,D,C), (D,C,A), (C,A,B) [Remark: I don't want to consider (1) the combintions with just one value, (2) the combination with all values and (3) the combination with no values. Thus I have 2^(n)-n-1-1 combinations for n different values]. I want to list all those combinations in two columns like demonstrated below.

Consider that I start with this column:

```
Col0
----
A
B
C
D
```

Out of Col0 I want to produce the 10 combinations using two columns:

```
Col1 Col2
---- ----
1    A
1    B
2    A
2    C
3    A
3    D
4    B
4    C
5    B
5    D
6    C
6    C
7    A
7    B
7    C
8    B
8    C
8    D
9    C
9    D
9    A
10   D
10   A
10   B
```

How do I do this in SQL? I use SQLite.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: For the `id` style column, the answer will depend on which dialect you're using.  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  PostgreSQL?  Etc?  Also, it's much easier if you have each combination on a single row, is that option viable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return all possible combinations of values on columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql)

Comment: @Eray Balkanli This looks similar but is actually another problem.

Comment: @MatBailie I'm using SQLite. Best regards. Unfortunately, I want to have several rows and not a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to enumerate the power set, by assigning each value a power of 2, then iterate from *1* to *2^n - 1* , and filter the elements which corresponding bit is set.

```
-- map each value with a power of 2 : 1, 2, 4, 8, 16
with recursive ELEMENTS(IDX, POW, VAL) as (
  -- init with dummy values 
  values(-1, 0.5, null)
  union all
  select IDX + 1,
    POW * 2,
    -- index the ordered values from 0 to N - 1
    ( select COL0 
      from DATA d1 
      where (select count(*) from DATA d2 where d2.COL0 < d1.COL0) = IDX + 1)
  from ELEMENTS 
  where IDX + 1 < (select count(*) from data)
), POWER_SETS(ITER, VAL, POW) as (
  select 1, VAL, POW from ELEMENTS where VAL is not null
  union all
  select ITER + 1, VAL, POW
  from POWER_SETS
  where ITER < (select SUM(POW) from elements) )
select ITER, VAL from POWER_SETS
-- only if the value's bit is set
where ITER & POW != 0
```

EDIT: 2nd version, with help from [MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie). Only one of the CTE is recursive, and singleton subsets are excluded.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  -- number the values
  elements(val, idx) AS (
    SELECT d1.col0, (select count(*) from DATA d2 where d2.COL0 < d1.COL0)
    FROM DATA d1
  ), 
  -- iterate from 3 (1 and 2 are singletons) 
  -- to 2^n - 1 (subset containing all the elements)
  subsets(iter) AS (
    VALUES(3)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT iter + 1
    from subsets
    WHERE iter < (1 << (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elements)) - 1
  )
SELECT iter AS Col1, val AS Col2
FROM elements
CROSS JOIN subsets
-- the element is present is this subset (the bit is set)
WHERE iter & (1 << idx) != 0
-- exclude singletons (another idea from MatBailie)
AND iter != (iter & -iter)
ORDER BY iter, val
```

Comment: Assuming the existence of a sufficiently large numbers table, this can be simplified quite a lot.  Here's a fiddle with my answer, creating a numbers table, then my simplification of your answer...  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=b938b497fdd904c9fed077b3fd5a2712

Comment: Can't look right now. I have to admit that my solution is not very pretty, it took me some time to find a solution to  problems like calculate power without a power operator / function or numbering the values without a row_num function / pseudo field. Very interesting question

Comment: I managed to avoid needing power and just used `<<` Binary Left Shift.

Comment: As for *n == n & -n* when *n* is a power of 2, I would definitely not have thought of it alone

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution, but it requires two changes...

1. Each item must be given an `id` *(starting from 1)*
2. The output id's may not be sequential

```
 id | datum
----+-------
  1 |   A
  2 |   B
  3 |   C
  4 |   D
```

*(The output `id`'s I calculate are effectively identifiers for each **Permutation**, but I don't output permutations you're not interested in...)*

```
 group_id | datum
----------+-------
    6     |   A
    6     |   B

    7     |   A
    7     |   C

    8     |   A
    8     |   D

    12    |   B
    12    |   C

    13    |   B
    13    |   D

    18    |   C
    18    |   D

    32    |   A
    32    |   B
    32    |   C

    33    |   A
    33    |   B
    33    |   D

    38    |   A
    38    |   C
    38    |   D

    63    |   B
    63    |   C
    63    |   D
```

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=87d670ecaba8b735cb3f95fa66cea96b

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=26e4f59874009ef95367d85565563c3c

```
WITH
  cascade AS
(
  SELECT
    1          AS depth,
    NULL       AS parent_id,
    id,
    datum,
    id         AS datum_id
  FROM
    sample

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    parent.depth + 1,
    parent.id,
    parent.id * (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM sample) + child.id - 1,
    child.datum,
    child.id
  FROM
    cascade  AS parent
  INNER JOIN
    sample   AS child
      ON child.id > parent.datum_id
),
  travelled AS
(
    SELECT
      depth       AS depth,
      parent_id   AS parent_id,
      id          AS group_id,
      datum       AS datum,
      datum_id    AS datum_id
    FROM
      cascade
    WHERE
       depth NOT IN (1, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sample))

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      parent.depth,
      parent.parent_id,
      child.group_id,
      parent.datum,
      parent.datum_id
    FROM
      travelled   AS child
    INNER JOIN
      cascade     AS parent
        ON parent.id = child.parent_id
)
SELECT
  group_id,
  datum
FROM
  travelled
ORDER BY
  group_id,
  datum_id
```

The first CTE walks all the available combinations *(recursively)* creating a directed graph.  At this stage I don't exclude combinations of one item, or all items, but I do exclude equivalent permutations.

Each node also has a unique identifier calculated for it.  There are gaps in these `id`s, because the calculation would also work for all *permutations*, even though they're not all included.

Taking any node in that graph and walking up to the final parent node *(recursively again)* will always give a different combination than if you started from a different node in the graph.

So the second CTE does all of those walks, excluding the combinations of "just one item" and "all items".

The final select just outputs the results in order.

The gaps in the `id`'s are probably avoidable but the maths is too hard for my head at the end of a working day.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I wanted since this gives me just every possible pair and not every combination.

Comment: @FeldO : I'm not sure you're being clear, at least I am confident I'm not certain what you mean.  I suggest expanding your example data, as this answer will solve for the example you gave.  Do you mean, for example, that `{a, b, c, d}` must ***also*** lead to the results `{a, b, c}`, `{b, c, d}`, etc?  If so, it becomes ***critical*** that you specify which DBMS you're using.  It would likely involve recursion; which MySQL can't do, Oracle and SQL Server do differently, etc, etc.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I would also want to get results like `{a, b, c}`. I made this clearer in my question now. I use SQLite.

Comment: @FeldO - Been in meetings, but I like this puzzle so spent the last half hour working it out :)  My answer functionally does what you have described...

Comment: @MatBailie excellent one. I think the second issue mentioned at the beginning can be easily solved using the dense_rank() over (order by group_id)

Comment: @RadimBača Except that sqlite doesn't support analytic functions :(

Comment: True, I can see you have really enjoyed :)

Answer (score 1):

If window functions and CTE is available then you can use the following approach

```
with data_rn as
(
    select d1.col0 col1, 
           d2.col0 col2, 
           row_number() over (order by d1.col0) rn
    from data d1
    inner join data d2 on d1.col0 > d2.col0
)
select rn, col1 from data_rn
union all
select rn, col2 from data_rn
order by rn
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d24cb59dff4c7387aa4d733990c32f9f)

Comment: Thank you, but this also just gives me all different pairs: [dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=49f856aa06aec00f7a56b65b1d0f8837). I now made it clearer in my question that I also need other combinations (see above).

Comment: @RadimBača - I'd appreciate any feedback or critique on my revised answer :)