# SQL subquery to get all combination in two different selected sets

Tags: sql

I have question to regarding a query I am writing:

I have two different (columns) data sets which I want to combine the result of, for instance:

```
Set 1:          Set 2: 

1               A
2               B
3               C
```

I want to create a query with the result:

```
resultset:

1 A
1 B
1 C
2 A
2 B
2 C
3 A
3 B
3 C
```

Is this possible using a JOIN or UNION?

So I get all possible combinations between the different rows?

Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Were set 1 or set 2 empty, what would you want; i.e. stll all results from the populated set with nulls in the other set's columns, or no results?

Comment: If you wanted to handle the empty scenario, go with `from table1 t1 full outer join table2 t2 on 1=1`; otherwise @GordonLinoff's answer's best

Comment: What did you try so far and what did you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return all possible combinations of values on columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql)

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is a [cartesian join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm)

```
SELECT 
    S1.col1,
    S2.col2 
FROM 
    S1,S2
```

Please see the example in the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cun4CGEcFrJUcdWdH2J7LK/0)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `cross join`:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col1
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2
order by t1.col1, t2.col1;
```

Comment: Indeed this works, I tested it out on SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0f40c/7

Thank you Gordon!