# SQL: How to generate non-existing combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a huge list by combination of two words. every word in dictionary should be combined with all other words. in other word I will have `Total^2` combinations. every single word has an distinct ID and I only produce the combination of two ids in the table of combinations.

I want to periodically check if any combination is missed so I can generate and add it to the database. I have found [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql) to generate all possible combinations but I don't know how to find non-existing combinations using SQL queries perhaps something like this:

```
select * from words a ... join words b 
where (a.id, b.id) not in (select * from combinaions)
```

If SQL has no direct solution for this, would you please suggest an algorithm to do that programmaticaly. Please note that there may be some missing **ID**s because I have deleted some words so I can not use a linear loop on integer numbers.

The table of **combinations** has two columns (first id, second id) both id are from table **words**

Comment: How is your data structured?

Comment: I edited the question: The table of combinations has two columns (first id, second id) both id are from table words @Zack

Comment: You're probably not far off with your 'something like this' suggestion. Maybe include the specific columns inside the `not in` select query, so `where (a.id, b.id) not in (select id1, id2 from combinations)`. Posting your table structure would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use cross join to have all possible combinations, then with the condition, you can remove the already existed ones.

```
Select * from words a cross join words b 
where not exists (select * from combinations c where c.first_id = a.id and c.second_id = b.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @VahiD noted, the `CROSS JOIN` is the central piece of the puzzle. Rather than using a sub-query, you can alternatively `LEFT JOIN` your existing combinations table to the `CROSS JOIN` of words, and check for `NULL`s (meaning that the given cartesian product combination doesn't exist in your existing combinations table).

For example:

```
WITH 
    -- sample data (notice that there's no word with ID of 3)
    words(word_id, word) AS
    (
        SELECT 1, 'apple'   UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'pear'    UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, 'orange'  UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, 'banana'
    )
    -- existing combinations
    ,combinations(first_id, second_id) AS
    (
        SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1, 5 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 4 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 5 UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, 5
    )
    -- this is the CTE you'll use to create the cartesian product
    -- of all words in your words table. You can also put this as a 
    -- sub-query, but I'd argue that a CTE makes it clearer.
    ,cartesian(w1_id, w1_word, w2_id, w2_word) AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM words w1, words w2
    )
-- the actual query
SELECT * 
FROM cartesian
    LEFT JOIN combinations ON
        combinations.first_id = cartesian.w1_id
        AND combinations.second_id = cartesian.w2_id
WHERE combinations.first_id IS NULL
```

Now, an important caveat is that this query doesn't consider a combination the same when `word1` and `word2` are switched. That is, `(1,2)` is not the same as `(2,1)`. However, resolving this is as simple as adjusting your join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cartesian
    LEFT JOIN combinations ON
        (combinations.first_id = cartesian.w1_id OR combinations.first_id = cartesian.w2_id)
        AND
        (combinations.second_id = cartesian.w1_id OR combinations.second_id = cartesian.w2_id)
WHERE combinations.first_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option.  Build out the full list in a sub query and left outer to your combinations table to find what's missing.

```
DECLARE @Words TABLE
    (
        [Id] INT
      , [Word] NVARCHAR(200)
    );

DECLARE @WordCombo TABLE
    (
        [Id1] INT
      , [Id2] INT
    );

INSERT INTO @Words (
                       [Id]
                     , [Word]
                   )
VALUES ( 1, N'Cat' )
     , ( 2, N'Taco' )
     , ( 3, N'Test' )
     , ( 4, N'Cake' )
     , ( 5, N'Apple' )
     , ( 6, N'Pear' );

INSERT INTO @WordCombo (
                           [Id1]
                         , [Id2]
                       )
VALUES ( 1, 2 )
     , ( 2, 6 )
     , ( 5, 3 )
     , ( 5, 1 );

--select from a sub query that builds out all combinations and then left outer to find what's missing in @WordCombo
SELECT          [fulllist].[Id1]
              , [fulllist].[Id2]
FROM            (
                    --Rebuild full list
                    SELECT     [a].[Id] AS [Id1]
                             , [b].[Id] AS [Id2]
                    FROM       @Words [a]
                    INNER JOIN @Words [b]
                        ON 1 = 1
                    WHERE      [a].[Id] <> [b].[Id] --Would a word be combined with itself?

                ) AS [fulllist]
LEFT OUTER JOIN @WordCombo [wc]
    ON [wc].[Id1] = [fulllist].[Id1]
       AND [wc].[Id2] = [fulllist].[Id2]
WHERE           [wc].[Id1] IS NULL;
```