# How to get the combination of data in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have the below data and need the desire output

It will use the combination of all column and return the possible output

```
XPO GL_CODE  
XPO GL_NAME  
PCARD GL_NAME  
PCARD CHART_OF_CODE
```

Expected Answer:

```
XPO GL_CODE  
XPO GL_NAME  
PCARD CHART_OF_CODE  
XPO GL_CODE  
PCARD GL_NAME  
PCARD CHART_OF_CODE
```

Comment: You haven't explain your data or logic here. What do you mean by *"combination of all column"*? Your data only has 1 column.

Comment: GL_CODE  and CHART_OF_CODE having single entry in table so it should come twice along with GL_NAME(XPO and PCARD)

Comment: You need to have a go and post your query at the point you get stuck.

Comment: Do you mean a cartesian product of two tables? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql) is what you are looking for... and please look at the question there, it is much clearer how the tables and the rusults should look like, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of all possibilities is known as a cross join (also known as a Cartesian join):

```
CREATE TABLE #t 
(
    col1 VARCHAR(20),
    col2 VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO #t (col1, col2) VALUES
('XPO','GL_CODE'),
('XPO','GL_NAME'), 
('PCARD','GL_NAME'),
('PCARD','CHART_OF_CODE');

WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM #t
),
cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM #t
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte1 
CROSS JOIN cte2;
```