# How to return all unique combinations from 1 column in sql?

Tags: sql

How to return all unique combinations from 1 column in sql?

For example the table I have

```
col
a
b
c
```

And the result is

```
col1, col2
a, a
a, b
a, c
b, b
b, c
c, c
```

(a, b) and (b, a) is the same combination

I found similar question to this 
([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql))
but my data is a string so I cannot compare it, or should I use something like rank() to give it a number?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT
    t1.col,
    t2.col
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.col <= t2.col
ORDER BY
    t1.col,
    t2.col;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

Comment: wow thank you for your fast reply and it works
I don't know that we can compare string like int

Comment: Thank you, this is my first post here. Now I will try to combine it with group by.

Comment: I am sorry it seems I missclick and delete your comment, *panic mode on*

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Tim-Biegeleisen for the answer

Another note for this question plus category, I thought we should use group by but it seems we don't have to

```
cat, col
c1,a
c1,b
c1,c
c2,b
c2,c
```

sql:

```
SELECT t1.cat,
   t1.col,
   t2.col
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
   ON t1.col <= t2.col and t1.cat=t2.cat
ORDER BY
   t1.cat,t1.col,t2.col;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ded42ed60bf2a3b17f0990592d5e07c0)