# Left join in sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the following SQL Server table:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| group | subgroup | position |  value   |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| D924  | A        | 50       | 9144142  |
| D924  | A        | 52       | 9268118  |
| D924  | A        | 60       | 9144588  |
| D924  | A        | 70       | 10116006 |
| D924  | A        | 110      | 9074177  |
| D924  | A        | 171      | 7367052  |
| D924  | A        | 180      | 10118595 |
| D924  | A        | 190      | 9074522  |
| D924  | B        | 150      | 12423396 |
| D955  | ...      | ...      | ...      |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I need to list all the `position` for every `subgroup` **within the same** `group`

Like so:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| group | subgroup | position |  value   |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| D924  | A        | 50       | 9144142  |
| D924  | A        | 52       | 9268118  |
| D924  | A        | 60       | 9144588  |
| D924  | A        | 70       | 10116006 |
| D924  | A        | 110      | 9074177  |
| D924  | A        | 171      | 7367052  |
| D924  | A        | 180      | 10118595 |
| D924  | A        | 190      | 9074522  |
| D924  | A        | 150      |          |
| D924  | B        | 50       |          |
| D924  | B        | 52       |          |
| D924  | B        | 60       |          |
| D924  | B        | 70       |          |
| D924  | B        | 110      |          |
| D924  | B        | 171      |          |
| D924  | B        | 180      |          |
| D924  | B        | 190      |          |
| D924  | B        | 150      | 12423396 |
| D955  | ...      | ...      | ...      |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I would like to achieve the result table in a single SQL query. Can you advise?

Comment: What have you tried so far, why didn't it work?

Comment: This this answer your question? [Return all possible combinations of values on columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4378811/2029983)

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a `DISTINCT` list of the `position` and  `[Group]` & `subgroup` values with a `LEFT JOIN` back to the table.

Doing a 2 `DISTINCT` queries will be expensive, so if you have a table of your groups and positions, I would suggest using those, rather than the CTEs:

```
WITH Groups AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            [group],
            subgroup
     FROM dbo.YourTable),
Positions AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            position
     FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT G.[Group],
       G.subgroup,
       P.Position,
       YT.[value]
FROM Groups G
     CROSS JOIN Positions P
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON G.[Group] = YT.[Group]
                               AND G.subgroup = YT.subgroup
                               AND P.Position = YT.Position;
```

Comment: This is very close to the result. The only problem is that your query give me the positions of other ```Groups```, i only want the positions 50,52,60,70,110,150,171,180 and 190. If there is the position 390 for the group D955, I don't want it in the D924 rows

Comment: Seems like you haven't given enough sample data here @JohanB . This a `DISTINCT` on the groups and subgroups though, so not entirely sure of the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to only want the value for the first "position" in each group.  That suggests `row_number()`:

```
select group, subgroup, position,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by group, position order by subgroup) = 1
             then value
        end) as value
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3fe6d262b06448543171adcdde0cbc9) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is giving me the exact same result at the source table

Comment: @JohanB . . . I added a db<>fiddle to illustrate that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Select distinct subgroups and positions first, then join them and outer join your table.

```
with sub as (select distinct group, subgroup from mytable)
   , pos as (select distinct group, position from mytable)
select
  sub.group. sub.subgroup, pos.position, t.value
from sub
join pos on pos.group = sub.group
left join mytable t on t.group = sub.group
                   and t.subgroup = sub.subgroup
                   and t.position = pos.position
order by t.group, t.subgroup, t.position;
```