# Populate a new table based on values of two colums

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a blank table (NEW_TABLE) with many columns, including COLUMN_1 and COLUMN_2.  I would like to populate NEW_TABLE with every possible combination of COLUMN_1 found in another table, OLD_TABLE, and values of 0 and 1 for COLUMN_2.  For an example, assume there are 2 distinct values in OLD_TABLE.COLUMN_1 (e.g.; 'red' and 'blue').  My desired result would be four rows in NEW_TABLE with

```
COLUMN_1 : COLUMN_2  
red      : 0  
red      : 1
blue     : 0
blue     : 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return all possible combinations of values on columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql)

Comment: Almost!  Can you advise on the additions required to update an existing table, as opposed to simply selecting?  In addition, the 0 and 1 do not appear in OLD_TABLE.

Comment: Use an `UPDATE` statement with a `JOIN`? You don't mention you want to `UPDATE` a table at all in the question.

Comment: Thanks, Larnu, my mistake.  Saying "update" instead of "populate" would have been more clear.  And yes, forgive the rookie question.  I am not clear of how to use the UPDATE with JOIN together.

Comment: You can use something like _INSERT INTO OLD_TABLE SELECT..._. The _SELECT..._ part is the query you made based in the first comment

Comment: If you need to **UPDATE** the table, then you need to be able to match each row you wish to "insert" to a **specific** row in the existing the table. What does this relationship look like?

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  Joel's suggestion worked.  And yes, it was an INSERT as opposed to UPDATE.  NEW_TABLE was empty when executing the query below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to generate your permutations:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Column_1 FROM OLD_TABLE) a
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1)) AS b(Column_2)
```

And that can now be part of an INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2)
SELECT a.Column_1, b.Column_2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Column_1 FROM OLD_TABLE) a
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1)) AS b(Column_2)
```

Comment: Success!  Thanks Joel, and everyone else on the thread.

Answer (score -1):

You are searching for a cross join.

I created a small table

```
create table TST_CJ
(
    ID    NUMBER,
    COLOR VARCHAR
);
```

I inserted 3 Values:

[image: Table]

With a crossjoin I can get the desired output:

```
SELECT a.id,
       b.color
FROM tst.TST_CJ a
         cross join tst.TST_CJ b
```

[image: Output]

Oh I just saw, that you don't have the values 0, 1 etc in a table. You can just cross join with a subquery then. Something like this:

```
SELECT b.id,
       a.color
FROM tst.TST_CJ a
         cross join (SELECT 1 as ID UNION ALL SELECT 2 as ID) b
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but I expect the reason is because of the screen shots. Those are not appreciated here.

Comment: Why? 
Screenshots are really fast and it is not an output you would want to copy somewhere. Its not like I screenshoted code, SQL, an error message or something you might want to copy.