# Assign an age to a person based on known population average but no Date of birth

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to use Postgres SQL to assign an age category to a list of househoulds, where we don't know the date of birth of any of the family members.

Dataset looks like:

| household_id | household_size |
| --- | --- |
| x1 | 5 |
| x2 | 1 |
| x3 | 8 |
| ... | ... |

I then have a set of percentages for each age group with that dataset looking like:

| age_group | percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 0-18 | 30 |
| 19-30 | 40 |
| 31-100 | 30 |

I want the query to calculate overall what will make the whole dataset as close to the percentages as possible and if possible similar at the household level(not as important). the dataset will end up looking like:

| household_id | household_size | 0-18 | 19-30 | 31-100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| x2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| x3 | 8 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | .... | ... |

I have looked at the ntile function but any pointers as to how I could handle this with postgres would be really helpful.

Comment: What is the link between `household_size` and `age_group`  (Guesssing is my main weak-point.... )

Comment: Can you adapt you sample data, in such a way that it is clear how the split is done? for `x3` the totals do not add up 8 is not equal to 2 + 4 + 3 ....

Comment: @Luuk if the household size is 5 there are 5 persons in the house and we want to allocate the 5 people to each of the 3 categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to post an answer with just a link so I figured I'll give it a shot and see if I can simplify [depesz `weighted_random`](https://www.depesz.com/2022/11/30/picking-random-element-with-weights/) to plain sql. The result is this slower, less readable, worse version of it, but in shorter, plain sql:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION weighted_random( IN p_choices ANYARRAY, IN p_weights float8[] ) 
  RETURNS ANYELEMENT language sql as $$
select  choice 
from
  ( select  case when (sum(weight) over (rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)) >= hit
            then choice end as choice
    from ( select unnest(p_choices) as choice, 
                  unnest(p_weights) as weight ) inputs, 
         ( select sum(weight)*random() as hit
           from unnest(p_weights) a(weight) ) as random_hit
    ) chances
where choice is not null
limit 1 
$$;
```

It's not [inlineable](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) because of aggregate and window function calls. It's [faster](https://dbfiddle.uk/EVDetb76) if you assume weights will only be probabilities that sum up to `1`.

The principle is that you provide any array of choices and an equal length array of weights (those can be percentages but don't have to, nor do they have to sum up to any specific number):

```sql
update test_area t
set ("0-18",
     "19-30",
     "31-100")
=   (with cte AS (
      select weighted_random('{0-18,19-30,31-100}'::TEXT[], '{30,40,30}') 
                as age_group
      from generate_series(1,household_size,1))
     select count(*) filter (where age_group='0-18')   as "0-18",
            count(*) filter (where age_group='19-30')  as "19-30",
            count(*) filter (where age_group='31-100') as "31-100"
     from cte)
returning *;
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/novFc1OD) showing that both his version and mine are statistically reliable.

Comment: @Zegarek...really appreciate the excessive effort here, works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

A **minimum** start could be:

```sql
SELECT
  household_id,
  MIN(household_size) as size,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN agegroup_from=0 THEN g ELSE 0 END),1) as g1,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN agegroup_from=19 THEN g ELSE 0 END),1) as g2,
  ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN agegroup_from=31 THEN g ELSE 0 END),1) as g3
FROM (
SELECT 
  h.household_id,
  h.household_size,
  p.agegroup_from,
  p.percentage/100.0 * h.household_size as g
FROM households h
CROSS JOIN PercPerAge p) x
GROUP BY household_id
ORDER BY household_id;
```

output:

| household_id | size | g1 | g2 | g3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 5 | 1.5 | 2.0 | 1.5 |
| x2 | 1 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.3 |
| x3 | 8 | 2.4 | 3.2 | 2.4 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jj6QGNL-)

Notes:

- Of course you should round the columns `g` to whole numbers, taking into account the complete split (g1+g2+g3 = total)
- Because g1,g2 and g3 are based on percentages, their values can change (as long as the total split is OK.... (see, for more info: [Return all possible combinations of values on columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378698/return-all-possible-combinations-of-values-on-columns-in-sql) )

Comment: interesting proposed solution thanks! it is close to something that would work but the one thing that is an issue is the rounding - in your example above - for x2 they will all round to zero and x3 will round to a total of 7 so the end total will be wrong. Do you know of a way to handle this?

Comment: one way to do the rounding could be: https://dbfiddle.uk/N2vuKTh_

Comment: again quite clever :) but you are always reducing the size of the third age group which means it will overall disproportionally smaller in the total across all households - it won't be 30% overall - it will be much less than that and the others will be higher - the end total breakdown percentage is more important than the individual row percentage breakdown but the total household size should be the same at the end. thanks. the percentage can vary a little but roughly the same as the breakdown

Comment: There **is** a reason, probably more than 1, I started the answer using: "A **minimum** start could be" 