# Inserting dummy data into Postgres table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dummy-data

I have got the following Postgres table:

```
create table test (
    id serial, 
    contract varchar, 
    amount0 int, 
    amount1 int, 
    price double precision
);
```

I would like to insert 100 rows of dummy data that conforms to the following:

– In column 'contract' there should be values out of 'abc', 'klm' and 'xyz'.

– In columns 'amount0' and 'amount1' there should be integer values out of 50, 60, 80, 100, 200.

– In column 'price' there should be values out of 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.5.

What I have come up with so far is this:

```
INSERT INTO test (amount0, amount1, price)
SELECT
  (SELECT val FROM unnest(ARRAY[50, 60, 80, 100, 200]) AS val ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT val FROM unnest(ARRAY[50, 60, 80, 100, 200]) AS val ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT val FROM unnest(ARRAY[1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.5]) AS val ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1)
FROM generate_series(1, 100);
```

But this doesn't do the trick. This statement always only uses '100' for column 'amount0', '50' for column 'amount1' and '2.1' for column 'price'.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Here is one way:  https://dbfiddle.uk/ymB0lsbt

Comment: @MikeOrganek That's definitely a very interesting solution. I had to reason about this at first until I realized that the number of rows this statement inserts is determined by the product of the number of the values it provides. Therefore I'd find it a bit hard to make this an accepted answer because it leaves you without a precise way to control the number of rows you get – even though as a result it does what I wanted to achieve. If no better solution is posted here however please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Put a `limit` on the `select` that feeds the `insert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [randomly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE) [subscript](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) the array of choices: ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jv5bBZFH))

```sql
INSERT INTO test (contract,amount0, amount1, price)
SELECT (ARRAY['abc','klm','xyz'])[(random()*2+1)::int],
       (ARRAY[50, 60, 80, 100, 200])[(random()*4+1)::int],
       (ARRAY[50, 60, 80, 100, 200])[(random()*4+1)::int],
       (ARRAY[1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.5])[(random()*3+1)::int]
FROM generate_series(1, 1e2, 1);

SELECT id, contract,amount0, amount1, price FROM test LIMIT 6;
```

| id | contract | amount0 | amount1 | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | klm | 50 | 100 | 2.1 |
| 2 | xyz | 100 | 100 | 1.5 |
| 3 | abc | 80 | 100 | 1.8 |
| 4 | xyz | 80 | 80 | 2.1 |
| 5 | xyz | 200 | 50 | 1.8 |
| 6 | xyz | 60 | 60 | 1.8 |

Note that this does what you intended to do, making each selection independently random. In effect, it's quite likely that you'll get duplicate entries. If you prefer to keep getting unique combinations until you run out, and only then start over, you can do something similar to [Mike's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244940/inserting-dummy-data-into-postgres-table?noredirect=1#comment136180557_77244940): ([demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/O905Uy4o))

```sql
INSERT INTO test (contract,amount0, amount1, price)
SELECT contract,amount0, amount1, price
FROM (values (50),(60),(80),(100),(200)) a(amount0),
     (values (50),(60),(80),(100),(200)) b(amount1),
     (values (1.5), (1.8), (2.1), (2.5)) c(price),
     (values ('abc'),('klm'),('xyz')   ) d(contract),
     generate_series(1, 1e2, 1) duplicator(n)
order by n, random()
limit 100;
```

[Here's a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75036007/5298879) if you find yourself in need of a *weighted* random, meaning that you want to define exactly how likely an option is, compared to the others.

---

The reason why your solution didn't work is that since your scalar subqueries don't depend in any way on the outer query, they were evaluated only once and re-used. You can check the plan by running it with [`explain analyze verbose`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html). You *could* trick the planner into thinking they somehow rely on the outer query by adding an outside reference, even if it does nothing ([demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/U3Azvnl3)) but the above does the same, in less code.

Comment: Demo 2: I played around with this a little and from mere visual inspection I couldn't find a difference in the results as compared to a more simplified version:

(Sorry, I wanted to post my amended code here, but there doesn't seem to be a possibility to do this. I left the amended code in the Fiddle. I basically left out the entire 'generate' line).

Can you maybe elaborate a bit on what your version does differently?

Comment: Demo 1 only seems to be working with integer values but not for text values (ie 'contract' should be from 'abc', 'klm', 'xyz').

Comment: Ad demo1: Prices are floats, so not only integers. You can use an array of anything just as well: https://dbfiddle.uk/QaYYCue-

Comment: Ad demo2: `generate_series()` is there to duplicate combinations. Along with ordering by the duplicate number before randomising selection, it guarantees you won't get duplicates until you exhaust the full set of unique possibilities. At the end of the demo you can see that grabbing 202 samples (`limit 202`) results in two combinations occuring exactly 3 times, while all the others occur exactly 2 times: given 100 unique, after exhausting all of them you need to start re-using, so by the time you got 202nd sample, you had to have used all unique combinations twice, then re-used two more.

Comment: Without duplication through `generate_series()`,  the `limit` clause dictates how many you get only up to the number of possible combinations. Up to the 100 you'd get what limit requested, above that you'd still keep getting only the 100, because there's nothing more to fetch. It's of course perfectly fine to skip it entirely, as long as you remember how many combinations you generate and how much of that you're using.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I made yours the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is everytime you run your command PostgreSQL took a seed number and send it to srand function. That is why with the same seed you get same values from your arrays. Therefore, you need call function as many times you want another value from your arrays, and you can do that creating functions. That will cause context switch, but that is the only thing that I can think of. Maybe someone else can correct me. Here is the code:

```
create table test (
    id serial, 
    contract varchar, 
    amount0 int, 
    amount1 int, 
    price double precision
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_amount()
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
  SELECT ('[0:4]={50, 60, 80, 100, 200}'::int[])[trunc(random()  * (4 - 1 + 1) + 1)::int];
$func$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_price()
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
  (SELECT ('[0:3]={1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.5}'::float[])[trunc(random()  * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1)::int]);
$func$;

INSERT INTO test (amount0, amount1, price)
SELECT
  random_amount(), random_amount(), random_price()
FROM generate_series(1, 100);

select * from test;
```

[Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/-KwTsiqO)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I shy away from using functions for this specific purpose of generating just 100 rows of dummy data. This seems a bit over engineered to me. I think it should be possible to achieve the goal with "just" a statement. Also in your Fiddle the random selection of price doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is on the right track for generating random values for the 'amount0', 'amount1', and 'price' columns. To also include the 'contract' column with values 'abc', 'klm', and 'xyz', you can modify your query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO test (contract, amount0, amount1, price)
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN random() < 0.33 THEN 'abc'
    WHEN random() < 0.66 THEN 'klm'
    ELSE 'xyz'
  END AS contract,
  (SELECT val FROM unnest(ARRAY[50, 60, 80, 100, 200]) AS val ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT val FROM unnest(ARRAY[50, 60, 80, 100, 200]) AS val ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1),
  (SELECT val FROM unnest(ARRAY[1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.5]) AS val ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1)
FROM generate_series(1, 100);

SELECT id, contract, amount0, amount1, price FROM test LIMIT 6;
```

This query uses the CASE statement to randomly select values for the 'contract' column based on probabilities. It assigns 'abc', 'klm', or 'xyz' with roughly equal probabilities to each row.